# upload a file to aws s3 with CLI by giving an url instead of a local file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

we use AWS S3 and CLI (aws command line interface) to move pictures from our server into a bucket. Now, we use another system which delivers those files (pictures) as urls. Instead of downloading this files and then uploading them to aws s3 with the mv command, we would prefer to upload the files directly from the url into s3 with cli. Question: is this possible? I assume no, because I was not able to find any information about this.

example:
old command: `aws s3 mv .       s3://.../demo.png`

new command: `aws s3 mv https://anurl/demosource.png s3://.../demo.png`

Comment: No this isn't possible out of the box; S3 CLI will not download a file for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can only copy files to/from:

- A local path
- An Amazon S3 bucket

It is not possible to request Amazon S3 to retrieve an object via a URL.

You could **write an AWS Lambda function** that downloads a file and uploads it to Amazon S3. This would be fast because it does not need to pass through your computer.